# JAR issue on Windows 2003

Tags: java

I have an application (myapplication.jar) running on Windows 2003. The application was running fine few days back on this server.

I am using a bat file to execute the Jar applicatin, for some reason it stopped working on it and I am unable to find the why?

If I copied the same folder to another server where JRE is already installed it works without an issue.

Cansome suggest me how do I find what is the issue. I have already checked the file type association, delete the temporary files (java cache and temporary files in windows)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: could you post the script in your bat file ?

Comment: @echo OFF 
set BACKTO=%CD% 
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin;%PATH% 
javaw.exe -jar "C:\Program Files\My Applicaction\dist\Application.jar" 
REM EXIT

Comment: turn ON @echo, then run the bat file form command line and see if it shows any errors

Comment: There is no error message. The command prompt struck on this line for some time and then command prompt closed.
javaw.exe -jar "C:\Program Files\My Applicaction\dist\Application.jar"

Answer (score 1):

Without any log, exception or stack trace it will be impossible to know what is causing the problem. Open the bat file in an editor and add at the end of line that starts with:

```
java -jar yourProgramBundledInA.jar > yourApp.log
```

this is going to redirect the console to `yourApp.log` file. Save the bat, run it and then look up the content of `yourApp.log`. There should be a clue why the application is failing.

Comment: Thanks for advise..
I tried the suggestion but there is no logs in log file. However the log files is creating. 
My Batch file is having following contents. 
@echo OFF
set BACKTO=%CD%


set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin;%PATH%


javaw.exe -jar "C:\Program Files\My Applicaction\dist\Application.jar" 

REM EXIT

Comment: Remove the `@echo OFF` and add after `javaw.exe -jar "C:\Program Files\My Applicaction\dist\Application.jar" > c:\application.log`

Comment: There is no error message and no logs are there in application.log file in C drive.

Comment: Do you get anything when you run `javaw.exe -jar "C:\Program Files\My Application\dist\Application.jar"` from command prompt?

Comment: When run the bat file it set the environment variables and try to exeucute the JAR application.
After few min the dos window disappear but no GUI window on screen..

Comment: Additionally it look like issue with Operating system. As there is no logs in event viewer I can not find what is causing this issue.

Comment: Do not double click on `bat` file, but enter the dos prompt and navigate to the folder where the `bat` file is. Then execute it by typing its name and after a while hit Ctrl+Break to have a thread dump. That will tell you where your Java program is stuck.